# SendARP not writing out to mac array

Tags: c++, winapi, network-programming, embedded

SendARP is not setting my mac array, so likewise when I try to convert the mac array to BYTE to convert it to human readable, it also gets random characters in it. also the memset does not seem to make MacAddr 0!

```
std::wstring GetMacAddress(IPAddr destip)
{
    DWORD ret;
    ULONG MacAddr[2] = {0};  //initialize instead of memset
    ULONG PhyAddrLen = 6;  /* default to length of six bytes */
    unsigned char mac[6]; 

    //memset(MacAddr, 0, sizeof(MacAddr));  //MacAddr doesn't get set to 0!
    //Send an arp packet
    ret = SendARP(destip , 0, MacAddr , &PhyAddrLen); //MacAddr stays

    //Prepare the mac address
    if (ret == NO_ERROR)
    {
        BYTE *bMacAddr = (BYTE *) & MacAddr;

        if(PhyAddrLen)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < (int) PhyAddrLen; i++)
            {
                mac[i] = (char)bMacAddr[i];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried numerous ways to get MacAddr to get set by the SendARP function, but it doesn't seem to work and it doesn't return an error.

Comment: Think a while what the address-of operator `&` does, and what would happen when you use it on an array...

Comment: Also think what happens when you dereference an uninitialized pointer (`unsigned char *mac` does not point at anything).

Comment: @RemyLebeau awww geez, can't believe I did that. Edited

Comment: @JoachimPileborg memset(MacAddr, 0, sizeof(MacAddr)) is what it should be. What is faster (or preferred):  ULONG MacAddr[2] = {0}; or the memset?

Comment: @dd = {0} hides a memset when large array are used, depending on the compiler I guess. Large was greater than 10 for my toolchain

Comment: Unfortunately, the MacAddr doesn't get set by SendARP and bMacAddr is still being filled with garbage chars. Any suggestions? I just tried the MSDN example just to see what is going on, and it was doing the same thing.

Comment: How sure are you that "garbage chars" is not actually the correct MAC?

Comment: @Casey is right. Those garbage characters are the mac address since `SendARP` stores it as binary and doesn't convert them to a text representation. I'm betting you have a misunderstanding of what casting to `char` actually does.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Ooops. As you guessed, I did have a misunderstanding what casting to char did (as well that SendARP gave the address back in binary). I read about that and found that printf has a function to convert hex values. Then to force it to bytes I used '.2' in printf. I finally used printf(%.2x%.2x....., mac[0], mac[1].......) and it gave me the result. Thanks again

Comment: it's not necessary to use C library functions to convert the data, especially since you are returning a `wstring` anyway. See my answer for a typesafe idiomatic C++ way of converting the mac address to a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Casting to `char` does not convert to a textual representation. If you want to convert to a textual representation one option is to use [`std::wstringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream)

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

std::wstring GetMacAddress(IPAddr destip)
{
    // ... snip ...

    std::wstringstream  out;
    for (int i = 0; i < (int) PhyAddrLen; i++)
    {
        out << std::setw(2) << std::setfill(L'0') << bMacAddr[i];
    }

    return out.str();
}
```

Comment: I replaced with this for loop and it worked well for returning a std::wstring

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
static const wchar_t *HexChars = L"0123456789ABCDEF";

std::wstring GetMacAddress(IPAddr destip)
{
    DWORD ret;
    BYTE MacAddr[sizeof(ULONG)*2];
    ULONG PhyAddrLen = sizeof(MacAddr);
    std::wstring MacAddrStr;

    ret = SendARP(destip, 0, (PULONG)MacAddr, &PhyAddrLen);
    if ((ret == NO_ERROR) && (PhyAddrLen != 0))
    {
        MacAddrStr.resize((PhyAddrLen * 2) + (PhyAddrLen-1));

        MacAddrStr[0] = HexChars[(MacAddr[0] & 0xF0) >> 4];
        MacAddrStr[1] = HexChars[MacAddr[0] & 0x0F];

        for (ULONG i = 1, j = 2; i < PhyAddrLen; ++i, j += 3)
        {
            MacAddrStr[j+0] = L':';
            MacAddrStr[j+1] = HexChars[(MacAddr[i] & 0xF0) >> 4];
            MacAddrStr[j+2] = HexChars[MacAddr[i] & 0x0F];
        }
    }

    return MacAddrStr;
}
```